# React hook arguments cause infinite rerendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect

I've got two custom react hooks one is just a wrapper for the other one.

The first one is a basic fetch hook, which returns the status and result or error.

```
interface State<T> {
  status: 'idle' | 'pending' | 'error' | 'success';
  data?: T;
  error?: string;
}

interface Cache<T> {
  [url: string]: T;
}

type Action<T> =
  | { type: 'request' }
  | { type: 'success'; payload: T }
  | { type: 'failure'; payload: string };

export function useFetch<T = unknown>(
  url: string,
  options?: RequestInit,
  cached = false
): State<T> {
  const cache = useRef<Cache<T>>({});
  const cancelRequest = useRef(false);

  const initialState: State<T> = {
    status: 'idle',
    error: undefined,
    data: undefined,
  };

  const fetchReducer = (state: State<T>, action: Action<T>): State<T> => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'request':
        return { ...initialState, status: 'pending' };
      case 'success':
        return { ...initialState, status: 'success', data: action.payload };
      case 'failure':
        return { ...initialState, status: 'error', error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'request' });

      if (cache.current[url] && cached) {
        dispatch({ type: 'success', payload: cache.current[url] });
      } else {
        try {
          const res = await fetch(url, options);
          const json = await res.json();
          cache.current[url] = json;

          if (cancelRequest.current) return;

          if (res.status !== 200) {
            dispatch({ type: 'failure', payload: json.error });
          } else {
            dispatch({ type: 'success', payload: json });
          }
        } catch (error) {
          if (cancelRequest.current) return;

          dispatch({ type: 'failure', payload: error.message });
        }
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      cancelRequest.current = true;
    };
  }, [url, options, cached]);

  return state;
}

export default useFetch;
```

The second hook is a wrapper which provides some fetch options like a header containing a cookie to the `useFetch` hook. This way I wont have to write the same code over and over to do some requests against my API. I've called it useAPICall

```
export const useAPICall = <T>(url: string, body?: any, method = 'GET') => {
  return useFetch<T>(
    apiEndpoint + url,
    {
      method,
      body,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'x-access-token': getCookie('token'),
      },
    },
    false
  );
};
```

`getCookie` returns the cookie called `token` from the document.

This is how I would use the `useAPICall` hook:

```
const { status, data, error } = useAPICall<Request>('/example/route');
```

My problem is that whenever I want to use the `useAPICall` or the `useFetch` hook, while providing an options object as argument, it causes infinite rerenders and a maximum update depth exceeded error.

I figured out the problem lies within the options dependency of `useEffect` in my `useFetch` hook, when I remove it from the dependency array the fetch request works nicely.

The only problem being that my linter tells me to include options in the dependency array because useEffect relies on it.

I'm now wondering how I can do it correctly.

Comment: Do you want to support changing options triggering a new request?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yeah because I want to use the useAPICall hook to provide a token in the header and some other routes would need dynamic body data with post request.

Comment: That's the answer to "Do you want to support providing options to the request?" The question is whether you care if a particular usage of the `useFetch()` hook is sensitive to the options changing during the lifetime of the component it's called from.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oh I'm sorry I didnt read correctly, I guess there could be use cases where I change the state of a component to trigger a new fetch request with a different body.

Comment: Okay, supporting that is possible, it's just more difficult to get right without violating the rules of hooks. I'll have an answer shortly.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts alright, thank you very much already. I've been sitting in front of that problem the whole day.

Comment: Updated my answer and provided two possible approaches, I'll let you pick which one you prefer. The first approach is easier, though the second one will be more flexible once it's implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is passing an object literal as `options` will cause the dependencies of your `useEffect()` to change every time the hook re-renders, meaning that, as you experienced, you'll be fetching repeatedly because the effect will run again with the new `options` reference every time the previous fetch has just completed.

In order to break the cycle, you'll need to either

- memoize the `options` you pass in from `useAPICall()`
- store your `options` in a `useRef()` within `useFetch()`

Additionally, since you want the fetch to be sensitive to `options` changing, if you decide on the second approach, you'll need to manually compare the new reference to the previous one each time the `useFetch()` hook renders, and only use the new reference if the value has changed.

Here's how you can implement the first approach in `useAPICall()`, leaving `useFetch()` alone:

```
export const useAPICall = <T>(url: string, body?: any, method = 'GET') => {
  const options = {
    method,
    body,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'x-access-token': getCookie('token'),
    },
  };
  const ref = useRef(options);

  if (
    ref.current.method !== options.method
    || ref.current.body !== options.body
    || ref.current.headers['x-access-token'] !== options.headers['x-access-token']
  ) {
    ref.current = options;
  }

  return useFetch<T>(
    apiEndpoint + url,
    ref.current,
    false
  );
};
```

Below is how you can implement most of the second approach, leaving `useAPICall()` alone, though I've left a comment where you'll need to flesh out the specifics of it:

```
interface State<T> {
  status: 'idle' | 'pending' | 'error' | 'success';
  data?: T;
  error?: string;
}

interface Cache<T> {
  [url: string]: T;
}

type Action<T> =
  | { type: 'request' }
  | { type: 'success'; payload: T }
  | { type: 'failure'; payload: string };

const initialState: State<any> = {
  status: 'idle',
  data: undefined,
  error: undefined,
};

function fetchReducer<T>(state: State<T>, action: Action<T>): State<T> {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'request':
      return { ...initialState, status: 'pending' };
    case 'success':
      return { ...initialState, status: 'success', data: action.payload };
    case 'failure':
      return { ...initialState, status: 'error', error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// if (prev == next) { return prev; } else { return next; }
function headersReducer(prev?: HeadersInit, next?: HeadersInit) {
  if (prev === next) {
    return prev;
  }

  if (!prev || !next) {
    return next;
  }

  if (
    // headers are equal
  ) {
    return prev;
  }

  return next;
}

// if (prev == next) { return prev; } else { return next; }
function optionsReducer(prev?: RequestInit, next?: RequestInit) {
  if (prev === next) {
    return prev;
  }

  if (!prev || !next) {
    return next;
  }

  if (
    prev.body === next.body
    && prev.cache === next.cache
    && prev.credentials === next.credentials
    && prev.headers === headersReducer(prev.headers, next.headers)
    && prev.integrity === next.integrity
    && prev.keepalive === next.keepalive
    && prev.method === next.method
    && prev.mode === next.mode
    && prev.redirect === next.redirect
    && prev.referrer === next.referrer
    && prev.referrerPolicy === next.referrerPolicy
    && prev.signal === next.signal
    && prev.window === next.window
  ) {
    return prev;
  }

  return next;
}

export function useFetch<T = unknown>(
  url: string,
  options?: RequestInit,
  cached = false
): State<T> {
  const cache = useRef<Cache<T>>({});
  const optionsRef = useRef<RequestInit>();
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchReducer, initialState);

  optionsRef.current = optionsReducer(optionsRef.current, options);
  const currentOptions = optionsRef.current;

  useEffect(() => {
    let cancelRequest = false;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'request' });

      if (cache.current[url] && cached) {
        dispatch({ type: 'success', payload: cache.current[url] });
      } else {
        try {
          const res = await fetch(url, currentOptions);
          const json = await res.json();
          cache.current[url] = json;

          if (cancelRequest) return;

          if (res.status !== 200) {
            dispatch({ type: 'failure', payload: json.error });
          } else {
            dispatch({ type: 'success', payload: json });
          }
        } catch (error) {
          if (cancelRequest) return;

          dispatch({ type: 'failure', payload: error.message });
        }
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      cancelRequest = true;
    };
  }, [url, currentOptions, cached]);

  return state;
}

export default useFetch;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explantation and for both fixes, I've implemented the first way now and it works perfectly! I'm gonna try the second approach sometime too.

Comment: @AlexanderHoerl if you're on React 16.13 or higher, check out my [`suspense-service`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/suspense-service) package, it might simplify your data fetching. It relies on React's new [`<Suspense />`](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-reference.html#suspensecomponent) component, which is part of their [experimental concurrent mode API](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-adoption.html).

Comment: In the second implementation why did you replace the cancelRequest ref with a simple variable? Is this more efficient?

Comment: yeah I'm above 16.13, I didn't even know about the new Suspense feature, thanks for pointing that out. Gonna check it out.

Comment: @AlexanderHoerl ah your `cancelRequest` ref wouldn't work properly. The whole point is to keep the cancellation in the closure where it occurred but the ref will propogate your cancellation between closures, effectively cancelling all future requests on any re-render where the effect dependencies change.